# Percorer 2 Arrays Distintos e Verificar quais Valores são Iguais

Tags: php, array, loop

Como fazer para percorrer 2 arrays distintos para verificar quais valores são iguais e após a verificação imprimir somente os valores iguais de ambos arrays?

As estruturas dos arrays estão na seguinte forma abaixo, tentei percorrer utilizando a function `in_array` mas não funciona, alguém consegue ajudar?

Array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1899
            [bola1] => 1
            [bola2] => 3
            [bola3] => 5
            [bola4] => 6
            [bola5] => 9
            [bola6] => 10
            [bola7] => 11
            [bola8] => 14
            [bola9] => 15
            [bola10] => 16
            [bola11] => 17
            [bola12] => 18
            [bola13] => 19
            [bola14] => 20
            [bola15] => 23
        )

)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [bola1] => 1
            [bola2] => 2
            [bola3] => 3
            [bola4] => 4
            [bola5] => 6
            [bola6] => 7
            [bola7] => 8
            [bola8] => 10
            [bola9] => 11
            [bola10] => 13
            [bola11] => 14
            [bola12] => 18
            [bola13] => 20
            [bola14] => 21
            [bola15] => 24
        )

)
```

Comment: A chave e o valor tem que ser iguais? Somente o valor? Somente a chave?

Comment: Somente o valor, por exemplo: o valor da chave [bola1] do Array 1 é 1, o valor da chave [bola1] do Array 2 é 1 então são iguais, imprime o 1. Já o valor da chave [bola2] do Array 1 é 3, o valor da chave [bola2] do Array 2 é 2, então não são iguais, captou a ideia?

Comment: Vê se a função array_intersect te serve https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php.

Comment: Não deu certo com essa função array_intersect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso o array está dentro de um outro array, tente isso.

$result = array_intersect($array1[0], $array2[0]);

print_r($result);

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou fazer assim ?

$arrNumber = [1,2,3,4,5];
$otherArr = [1,3,7,9];

foreach($arrNumber  as $arr){
  foreach ($otherArr as $v) {
    if($arr === $v){
      print 'Valores iguais:'. $v ."
";
    }
  }
}

se for um array dentro de um outro array percorre o primeiro nível e depois o segundo comparando os valores.